# Git recursive push

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to git and mostly used so far for backup. Here is the problem I am facing.

I have a root directory, R. Within this directory I have many others: A, B, C. I have a git repository with remote branch #1 set up in R and another repository with remote branch #2 in A. Now when I run

```
git push
```

from directory R, it won't actually push the content of A in repository #1. On the other hand, the contents of B and C (where there is no git repo initialized) is pushed.  Is this the standard behavior of git? If so, how can I recursively push everything below R (including other repositories)?
My remote branch #1 is on bitbucket, but I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: so you have `R/.git` and `R/A/.git` ? maybe you can use [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: out of curiosity, why do your have that setup? Any benefits it brings you?

Comment: @dubes: I want to share a project of mine (in A) with others, and meanwhile I want to keep a backup of my own of the whole R

Comment: @ymonad: yes, that's the structure. I give a look at git-submodule, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is expected behaviour. You say you are using git "mostly for backup", but that's not what Git is for. It is for tracking content in a directory, and it treats nested repositories as separate entities.